# Table with multiple tables many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, mysql

I created a minimal amount of code to reproduct my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableA (
    id int,
    name text,
    CONSTRAINT specimen_report_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableB (
    id int,
    tableA_id int,
    textB text,
    CONSTRAINT tableA_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tableA_id)
    REFERENCES TableA (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableC (
    id int,
    tableA_id int,
    textC text,
    CONSTRAINT tableA_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tableA_id)
    REFERENCES TableA (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableD (
    id int,
    tableA_id int,
    textD text,
    CONSTRAINT tableA_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tableA_id)
    REFERENCES TableA (id));

insert into TableA (id, name) values 
(1, 'A1'), (2, 'A2'), (3, 'A2');

insert into TableB (id, tableA_id, textB) values 
(1, 1, 'B1'), (2, 1, 'B2'),
(3, 2, 'B1'), (4, 2, 'B2'),
(5, 3, 'D1'), (6, 3, 'D2'), (7, 3, 'D3');

insert into TableC (id, tableA_id, textC) values 
(1, 1, 'C1'), 
(2, 2, 'C1'), (3, 2, 'C2'),
(4, 3, 'D1'), (5, 3, 'D2'), (6, 3, 'D3');

insert into TableD (id, tableA_id, textD) values 
(1, 1, 'D1'), 
(2, 2, 'D1'), (3, 2, 'D2'),
(4, 3, 'D1'), (5, 3, 'D2'), (6, 3, 'D3');

select * from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.tableA_id = a.id
left join TableC c on c.tableA_id = a.id
left join TableC d on d.tableA_id = a.id
--where id = 1 --return 1
--where id = 2 --return 4
--where id = 3 --return 27
```

I have multiple tables that create with the main table in this case TableA a many to many relationship. And the number of returned records grows very fast as I have more and more information in Tables B, C and D. Because the query returns combinations for each of the values of B, C and D.

I wonder where I made a mistake. Is it a problem in the database architecture or the query. Now as I analyze it, it seems to me that I have designed the database wrong, but before I redesign it I would still like to confirm my belief.

In my application I have so much data in tables B, C and D that it returns me ~2 million records. Tables B, C and D. They are very similar and actually by adding one more field I could put all the data in one table. But I don't know if this is the correct solution?

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result?

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: In your example each row in `A` has zero or more `B`s, zero or more `C`s, and zero or more `D`s. Your query prduces a row for every combination of values `(a, b, c, d)`. So for example if you have a row iin `A` that has 2 `B`s and 3 `C`s and 4 `D`s then you get `2 * 3 * 4 = 24` rows for that single `A`. What do you _want_ the result to be -- how do you want to show the `B`s, `C`s, and `D`s for an `A`?

Comment: Yes, you get a lot of results, and it is very rare that you need that many result. Rare, but not impossible. However, we have no idea what the data represents, or what you want to do with it, which is kind of important for the question whether you designed your database correctly.

Comment: Note that you have duplicated the foreign key constraint names in your schema.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough In my application, table A represents the games, table B, C, D, etc. represent the attributes/properties of these games. (Such as categories or mechanics). I would like to display all these values. 
That is, Game XYZ, has categories K1, K2, K3 and mechanics M1, M2, M3. In fact, there is more data of this type. Which makes it take a very long time to execute such a query and retrieve this information. I wonder if it is good to make table B, C, D into one table BCD. And only have one many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Provide **desired output** for shown sample data.

Comment: You say _...to display..._ . But: display _how_?

Answer (score -3):

The problem you are facing is related to the number of records returned in the join query you are performing. This happens because you used a join to join Tables B, C, and D to Table A based on tableA_id. Because Tables B, C, and D have many entries for each tableA_id, the join results will produce a lot of combinations, especially if the data in Tables B, C, and D is quite large.

The solution to overcome this problem depends on the application needs and the desired database design. Some options to consider:

The solution to overcome this problem depends on the application needs and the desired database design. Some options to consider:

Query Optimization: If you only need a small portion of the data returned, consider adding a more specific WHERE condition to limit the number of rows returned.

Indexes: Make sure you have created appropriate indexes on the columns used in join and where conditions to improve query performance.

Normalization: If possible, consider normalizing your table structure by combining Tables B, C, and D into one table with additional columns to differentiate data types (B, C, or D).

Paging: If possible, implement a paging feature to divide query results into smaller chunks.

Caching: If data changes infrequently, consider using caching techniques to store frequently needed query results and reduce load on the database.

Here's an example query you can try to apply to address the issue of the number of records returned in your join query:

First, if you only need a small portion of the data returned, add a more specific WHERE condition to limit the number of rows returned. For example, to get Table A data along with related data from Tables B, C, and D for id = 1:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA a
 LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.tableA_id = a.id
 LEFT JOIN TableC c ON c.tableA_id = a.id
 LEFT JOIN TableD d ON d.tableA_id = a.id
 WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Second, if possible, use paging features to divide query results into smaller chunks. For example, using LIMIT to limit the number of rows returned:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA a
 LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.tableA_id = a.id
 LEFT JOIN TableC c ON c.tableA_id = a.id
 LEFT JOIN TableD d ON d.tableA_id = a.id
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; -- Gets the first 10 rows
```

You can change the OFFSET value to get other parts of the data.

Using this query will help limit the number of rows returned from the join result, depending on your application's needs.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?